# Show if the site are currently under maintenance or not, but not working

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I coded a function to check if the site is currently under maintenance or not, but not working.
This is the useState from the App.js

```
const [isOnMaintenance, setIsOnMaintenance] = useState(false);
...
<BrowserRouter isOnMaintenance={isOnMaintenance}>
        <Routes>
          <Route path='*' element={<Notfound/>} />
          <Route path="/" element={<Homepage/>} />
          <Route path="/home" element={<Homepage/>} />
          <Route path="/about" element={<Aboutpage/>} />
          <Route path="/picture" element={<Picturepage/>} />
          <Route path="/projects" element={<Projectpage/>} />
        </Routes>
</BrowserRouter>
```

And I passed it down to the Homepage.js from the Router-Dom.

```
import React from 'react'
import { Div,
        } from "atomize";
import Maintenance from '../../components/Maintenance/Maintenance';

const Homepage = (isOnMaintenance) => {
  if (isOnMaintenance === true) {
    return (
      <Maintenance />
    )
  }
  else {
  return (
      <Div>
        The website is ok
      </Div>
    )
  }
}

export default Homepage
```

My website still returns the second return, and the first one is not working.

Comment: You need to post what sets `isOnMaintenance` to true.  That code as is looks like it should be behaving as you describe.

Comment: I haven't done it yet, I set isOnMaintenance to false but still not render the page properly

Answer (score 1):

Your code nested to much and it's not clean

Remove the if else loop of your's like this:

```
import React from 'react'
import { Div,
        } from "atomize";
import Maintenance from '../../components/Maintenance/Maintenance';

const Homepage = (isOnMaintenance) => {
  
  return (
      <Div>
        The website is ok
      </Div>
    )
  
}

export default Homepage
```

In your app.js file you need to import your Maintenance component and add this code :

```
if (process.env.NODE_ENV !== "production"){
   return <Maintenance/> 
}
```

than,when your app will display Maintenance each time that you not in prod.

FYI , `NODE_ENV` is an environment variable made popular by the express web server framework. When a node application is run, it can check the value of the environment variable and do different things based on the value. NODE_ENV specifically is used (by convention) to state whether a particular environment is a production or a development environment. A common use-case is running additional debugging or logging code if running in a development environment.

Comment: Can I have the explanation for that usage? I'm new to Reactjs. Thank you.

Comment: the answer had been edited for you.